# Dropdown Selected Object Appears as String

Tags: flutter

I am building a scheduling app and when I want to create a new shift, I have two dropdowns that are dependant on another.

One dropdown is to choose a designation for an employee and the other dropdown is there to show all capable employees for the chosen designation.

For the second dropdown (employee dropdown) I need to access an employee's property, specifically its Firestore document id.

In the beginning, I would only choose an employee's name and thus it was impossible to add the new shift to the employee's shifts sub-collection.

Now I edited my code and it is possible to choose the employee object instead of only the employee's name parameter.

What I do not understand is, that when I choose an employee object, then the employee's name is visible, which is actually what I want but makes no sense. It would not make any sense since my Dropdown is of type Employee object and **NOT** String.

Here is my implementation:

```
Employee _employeeObj;
String _designation;
String _employeeName;

Widget _buildEmployeeDropdown() {
    //todo: I should probably wait for the user to choose designation before 
    //todo... fetching the capable employees
    return BlocBuilder<EmployeesBloc, EmployeesState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is EmployeesLoading) {
          //todo let the user know that after choosing the designation
          //todo... the employee dropdown will be available
          return Container(child: Text('Loading'),);
        } else if (state is EmployeesLoaded) {
          return InputDecorator(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.user),
              labelText: 'Employee',
            ),
            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton<Employee>(
                items: state.employees.map((Employee employee) {
                  return new DropdownMenuItem<Employee>(
                    value: employee,
                    child: Text(employee.name),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (Employee newEmployee) {
                  setState(() {
                    _employeeName = newEmployee.name;
                    _parentId = newEmployee.id;
                    _employeeObj = newEmployee;
                  });
                },
                value:_employeeObj,
              ),
            ),
          ); 
        }
      },
    );
  }

   Widget _buildDesignationField() {
    return BlocBuilder<DesignationsBloc, DesignationsState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is DesignationsLoading) {
          return Container(
            child: Text('Loading'),
          );
        } else if (state is DesignationsLoaded) {
          return InputDecorator(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.tasks),
              labelText: 'Designation',
            ),
            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                items: state.designations.map((Designation designation) {
                  return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: designation.designation,
                    child: Text(designation.designation),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (String newDesignation) {
                  // call only the capable employees for this designation
                  BlocProvider.of<EmployeesBloc>(context)
                      .add(LoadEmployeesWithGivenDesignation(designation: newDesignation,date: widget.daySelected,));
                  setState(() {
                    _designation = newDesignation;
                    // After changing the designation, I have to set the employeeName
                    // to null, otherwise I will be getting errors, since my 
                    // employee dropdown does not contain the name for the new designation
                    _employeeName = null;
                    _employeeObj = null;
                  });
                },
                value: _designation == null ? 'open' : _designation,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Employee **4** is the name of the employee.

[image]

Comment: What do you not understand ? you pass an 'Employee' object to your 'DropDownMenuItem' and you display the value calling 'employee.name'. It's normal to have the name displayed

Comment: @FPerroch I am displaying this `value:_employeeObj` after I click on an option from the dropdown. I am only showing a string `employee.name` while choosing from the dropdown.

Comment: You need to share your Employee Object but I think that the `toString()` method of your object return the `name` of the employee ;)

Comment: @FPerroch what does it mean 'to share your Employee Object'? It can not be from the toString of my Employee Object => `@override
  String toString() {
    return 'Employee(designation: $designation, email: $email, hiringDate: $hiringDate, id: $id, name: $name, salary: $salary, weeklyHours: $weeklyHours, currentWeekEreignis: $busyMap)';
  }` The name value is in the middle of this chaos :) and in the DropDown it appears at the beginning.

Comment: Sorry I said anything ! the value displayed by the DropDown is the same as the items so here, it's the `Text(employee.name)` of your `DropdownMenuItem`